# Why robocopy still copy an open file, opened by txt editor in windows

Tags: command-line, batch, file-transfer, robocopy, notepad

From wikipedia, it is told that robocopy will skip copying files in open status.

However, when it is under test for robocopy behaviour, the robocopy still copy the opened file by the most simple text editor in windows. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Windows not warning about file in use for certain programs?](https://superuser.com/questions/853420/why-is-windows-not-warning-about-file-in-use-for-certain-programs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, as @fejyesynb correctly noted, Notepad doesn't keep an active file handle – it opens the file, quickly reads (or writes) the data, and closes the file again. The *data* is on screen, but the file is actually closed the whole time.

Second, Windows has inherited from MS-DOS the concept of "share modes" as a simple form of file locking. When opening a file you can choose whether to share it for read/write, for only reading, or not at all.

For example, if your program (robocopy) wants to open the file for reading (FileAccess.Read), it will *only* succeed if all existing file handles allow the 'read' share mode (or if there aren't any open file handles at all). But if the file was opened with "share none", then you'll get "File in use" if you try to open it for *any* purpose.

You can perform this in PowerShell, by calling the low-level .NET [System.IO.File.Open()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=netframework-4.7.2) function:

```
$fh = [System.IO.File]::Open($path,
                             [System.IO.FileMode]::Open,
                             [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read,
                             [System.IO.FileShare]::None)
```

The 4th parameter can be any [System.IO.FileShare enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare?view=netframework-4.7.2) value, for example:

- `[System.IO.FileShare]::None` – share nothing
- `[System.IO.FileShare]::Read` – share read (block write/delete)
- `[System.IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite` – share read/write (block delete)

When you're done:

```
$fh.Close()
```

Comment: Notepad doesn't open the file. [It maps the file directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45645766/995714)

Answer (score 3):

Because you are thinking of a different meaning of "open".

Notepad (and all other text editors I know) opens a file for reading, then you see it on your screen. Then it *closes* the file while you can still see the contents (now in RAM).

If, for example, you have `fd = open("file.txt", FLAGS);` and it isn't (yet) closed by `close(fd)`, then it wouldn't be copied with robocopy.

Comment: Thus, how could I simulate the case to keep opening the file in a simple manner? I would like to show the robocopy properties that it will avoid copying open file properties. But can't find a simple way to keep opening it

Comment: The simplest way I can think of (on Windows) is to build a simple C program that opens a file, sleeps for say 60 seconds and closes afterwards. You will then have 60 seconds to test robocopy.

Comment: @cuda For a more concrete answer, open a new question (1 question per post on SE)

Comment: Apart from making a program and place in that remote session computer, any more simple way by windows scripts? dont have ide of C program/JAVA/C#

Comment: I don't think scripts are low level enough for system `open` and `close` calls

Comment: the stackexchange enforce the rules to create another question in 40 mins later. Is there any other way to keep file open without writing the most simple C program, do not have that tools of IDE or privilege to install

Comment: guess that something like this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6231646-57df-43ca-86db-dc04d93c32de/opening-text-file-with-vbscript?forum=ITCG

Comment: opened another question here https://superuser.com/questions/1360787/how-to-simply-keep-a-file-in-open-status-without-help-of-program-in-c-language-e but seems not working with that scripts... the file still get copied...robocoy does not ignore copying it

Comment: @fejyesynb: Practically everything *above Cmd's level* can handle it. PowerShell has full .NET runtime access, for example.

Comment: @grawity it will be much appreciated if you could provide some insights how to work to open and hold the file handle without close file, then I run the robocopy to see if it really works with avoid copying the opened file.

Comment: This is wrong, Notepad [maps the file directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45645766/995714) and doesn't open then close the file

Answer (score 1):

## Depends on how the file is opened!

Many applications **load the whole file to memory and close** it, thus in fact the file is not in used. This of course can't be used with huge files, therefore editors for large text files have various techniques to work efficiently, like loading just a part of the file to memory at a moment

Many others do keep the file handle opened, but they **[don't lock the file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26198169/995714)**, allowing other applications to read/copy the file

**Notepad OTOH [maps the file to memory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180521-00/?p=98795)**, resulting in a file that doesn't *look like being opened*. That means what fejyesynb said is not correct, because it doesn't load the file to RAM at all

For more information you can read

- [Why is Windows not warning about file in use for certain programs?](https://superuser.com/q/853420/241386)
- [Notepad beats them all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45644934/995714)
- [Powershell: Get-Content without locking file](https://superuser.com/q/1184789/241386)