# How to simply keep a file in open status without help of program in C language/etc.. by using windows bare basic features?

Tags: batch, filesystems, file-transfer, robocopy

[Why robocopy still copy an open file, opened by txt editor in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1360780/why-robocopy-still-copy-an-open-file-opened-by-txt-editor-in-windows)

Further to above question, how could it be the simplest way to keep an file opened in a bare windows env like server 2016 environment to show the robocopy properties that it will avoid copying opened file or even show error in log for testing purpose?

either by batch or other existing function in windows server could be acceptable

VBS 
sth like this does not work

Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForWriting, True)

Do
MyFile.WriteLine "Hello world!"
Loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Copied from [Why robocopy still copy an open file, opened by txt editor in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1360780/why-robocopy-still-copy-an-open-file-opened-by-txt-editor-in-windows)*

Windows has inherited from MS-DOS the concept of "share modes" as a simple form of file locking. When opening a file you can choose whether to share it for read/write, for only reading, or not at all. Some scripting interpreters will always use "share all".

However, you can use any .NET-runtime language and the 4-parameter [System.IO.File.Open()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=netframework-4.7.2) function. Chances are that your Windows system has a C# compiler (csc.exe) hidden somewhere, but nowadays it's easier to do the same in PowerShell:

```
$fh = [System.IO.File]::Open($path,
                             [System.IO.FileMode]::Open,
                             [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read,
                             [System.IO.FileShare]::None)
```

The 4th parameter can be any [System.IO.FileShare enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare?view=netframework-4.7.2) value, for example:

- `[System.IO.FileShare]::None` – share nothing
- `[System.IO.FileShare]::Read` – share read (block write/delete)
- `[System.IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite` – share read/write (block delete)

When you're done:

```
$fh.Close()
```